# knockout select change and json

Tags: knockout.js

My json data is

```
{"person":
        [
        {"Name":"Name1",
        "City":"1",
        "PostCode":1234
        },
        {"Name":"Name2",
        "City":"2",
        "PostCode":12
        }]
}
```

My UI is,

```
<tbody id="container" data-bind="foreach: person">

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input id="Name" style="width: 100px" type="text" data-bind="value:Name" class="dynamic" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <select id="City" style="width: 100px" data-bind="value: City" class="dynamic" >                            
                                    <option value="0">NY</option>
                                    <option value="1">NJ</option>
                                    <option value="2">CA</option>                                 
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="PostCode" disabled="disabled" style="width: 100px" type="text" data-bind="value: PostCode, enable: City() == '0' || City() == '1'"" class="dynamic"/>
                            </td>
```

```
<select id="City" style="width: 100px" data-bind="value: County" class="dynamic" >                            
                                <option value="0">Test0</option>
                                <option value="1">Test1</option>
                                <option value="2">Test2</option>                                 
                            </select>
                               </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
```

my viewModel is,

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var jsonData = {};
    $.getJSON("test.json", function (data) {
        jsonData = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);       
        ko.applyBindings(jsonData);
    }
);
</script>
```

What I need to do is when I change my dropdown text, I have to change my county dropdown as per the selected city. **My dropdown text are not from my json**. I tried to use "subscribe" option.  Anyone can help me please?

Comment: On which value of the selected option you want to enable the textbox ?

Comment: value ="1" and value ="2". (Above is an example code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *enable* binding on your postalcode textbox like:

```
<td>
     <input id="PostCode" disabled="disabled" style="width: 100px" type="text" 
      data-bind="
          value: PostCode, 
          enable: City() == '1' || City() == '2'" 
     class="dynamic"/>
</td>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much indeed. But It doesn't make any change. I started to learn knockout just from few days before. I am stuck with this.

Comment: What I need to do is when I change my dropdown text, I have to change my county dropdown as per the selected city. My dropdown text are not from my json. I tried to use "subscribe" option. Anyone can help me please?